# Elastic Search : Adding nodes to cluster on the fly

Tags: elasticsearch, distributed-system

I want to setup Elastic-Search cluster. As it is a distributed system, I should be able to add more nodes on the fly(meaning: adding new nodes after it is deployed once). How is this done and how does Elastic-search manage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch handles this using [Zen Discovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html)

> The zen discovery is the built in discovery module for elasticsearch
>   and the default. It provides unicast discovery, but can be extended to
>   support cloud environments and other forms of discovery.

This is done through `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file. You have two options - multicast and unicast:

- Multicast lets your new node to connect to your cluster without specifying IPs, however it's not recommended.
- Unicast. You specify a list of nodes in your cluster (their IPs).

Both ways, your started node will try to ping other nodes and if their cluster names are matching, it will join it.

Configuration example:

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch_media
node.name: "media-dev"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["153.32.228.250[9300-9400]", "10.122.234.19[9300-9400]"]
```

Comment: If I want to add a third node, only the third will have configuration change or will add the nodes needs to be changed. If all nodes needed to be changed, should they be restarted?

Comment: It should be enough to configure third node only. You won't need to restart other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to edit the main configuration file on your new node and change the cluster name to the cluster you are currently running. Of course the new node must be discoverable. This depends on your network settings.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to write a script which will accept command line arguments about cluster name and IP addresses, authentications etc.,
- This script will open and modify elasticsearch.yml file on the remote server.